# Would you have logging as a separate service when using Service Bus implementation?

Tags: architecture, soa, nservicebus, servicebus

Using a service bus implementation.
When an email is read by a particular user we raise an event that the email has been read.
We have a subscriber that then picks up on this event when it is raised.
When the email is read we want to perform an action and then log that the email has been read in a database.

My question is:-
Would you 
a) Raise another event which would then be subscribed to by a logging service which would listen to all logging events raised for this and other systems?
b) Have the subscriber listening for the email read event log that the email had been read?
c) Do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you following DDD principles, if so, why would you want to have a service just to log?

If that "logging" is part of the requirements for the business, which would mean a state change in your repository, then it needs to be part of the transaction that raises the event raised after the user has read the email, not the other way round,  but it seems to me that in a DDD point of view having a separate service just to log is not the best approach, also if you have a central service that handles all the messages in your system what would the point be in having a distributed system in the first place?

"Would you a) Raise another event which would then be subscribed to by a logging service which would listen to all logging events raised for this and other systems?"

I don't think you should do it, because an event handler should not publish another event it should instead submit a command.

On the other side, why can't you just have that log done, in the service that raises the event? because that is where the action is happening.

Marco

Comment: I totally agree that it should be part of the same transaction. Within the department one of the guys has said that he wants almost a shared logging service. I would suggest this is not the way to go as auditing is not a separate service and should not be treated as such and managed as part of the same transaction.

Comment: You're right, there is no need to such a service, but as you know auditing a distributed system is not an easy task, but then again, we have tools like splunk :)

Comment: haven't come across splunk before?

Comment: You should. Say you have a dozen of services running in different machines, you know a mess to debug, lots of logging files to read, with splunk you can aggregate those sources and have the information available in one place, you can also use widgets to help you represent that that, have a go, I highly recomend it.

Comment: ahh brilliant will have a look into that. Seems would be just what we wanted for this type of scenario :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether or not you want the logging execution as part of the current transaction.  As your system grows in volume you may find that an optimization will be to send a message to another endpoint to complete the logging.  I wouldn't bother with pub/sub on the logging, you should be able to just use a simple point to point communication.

Comment: Agreed. I would suggest the same thing. Just started working with service based architecture as implemented by another guy in the department and service bus would seem to suggest that transactions should not cross service boundaries.

Comment: Yes, transactions like the ones provided by tools such as dtc are not the way to go, but semantic transitions still exist.

Answer (score 0):

What about having an audit queue on the subscriber? You could then have a separate handler to pull messages off the audit queue and log the events your interested in (in this case the email has been read event).

Comment: And why would he want to audit the queue?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you said,

> we raise an event that the email has been read. We have a subscriber that then picks up on this event when it is raised. When the email is read we want to perform an action and then log that the email has been read in a database.

So, you raise the "Email Read" event, and the subscriber picks it up and performs an action. Currently, after performing the action, no logging takes place.

You could either have the same subscriber perform the logging after performing the action, or perform the logging in parallel to the action, or you could have a second subscriber listen to the "Email Read" event and perform the logging.

It depends on whether the logging is meant to be transactional with respect to the "action", whether the logging must be reliable, and other such considerations. Of course, there are the normal considerations of maintainability, management, audit, etc.

In other words, "it depends".

Comment: This is more of an audit than anything. I was thinking along the lines of having the audit completed when the action email read is recognised. It is just that someone in the dept seems to think logging should be a separate function that can be shared by any number of services.